# python regex find lowercase followed by capital letter

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I feel like I have to apologize in advance for this one, but I've searched for answers and they seem to tell me what I'm doing is correct.

I'm trying to set a DataFrame column to True if another column has instances of a lowercase letter immediately followed by an uppercase letter.

What I tried was this:

```
    cities['multiteam'] = cities['team'].apply(lambda x: pd.notna(re.search(r'[A][a]',x)))
```

That's setting all the results to False, so I figured maybe I was doing something wrong with my lambda function and I made the following to debug just the re.search() part:

```
cities['multiteam'] = pd.notna(re.search(r'[a][A]','OneTwo'))
```

That's also setting all the results to False. And there I'm stuck.

Comment: [`([a-z])[A-Z]`](https://regex101.com/r/cwiFPc/1).

Comment: There is https://regex101.com/ to play with regular expressions (switch to Python flavor). You want something like "[a-z][A-Z]" as regex. If you need to process non-English characters, things may become a bit more complicated.

Comment: You may actually want `df['team'].str.contains('[a-z][A-Z]')` if you're looking for True/False

Answer (score 0):

The following code is useful only to look for a letter 'A' followed by the lower case 'a'.

```
cities['multiteam'] = cities['team'].apply(lambda t: pd.notna(re.search(r'[A][a]',t)))
```

You may need to change it if you want to check it for all letters. Maybe replace that line with something like this:

```
cities['multiteam'] = cities['team'].apply(lambda t: pd.notna(re.search(r'[A-Z][a-z]',t)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never to apologise about asking questions.  Using `apply` is quite slow, try and use the `str.contains` which can accept a regex pattern.

```
cities.assign(multiteam=cities.team.str.contains('[a-z][A-Z]'))
```

The `assign` above is pandas new recommend way of assigning columns.

The `str.contains` works with regex and fixed strings, much faster than `apply`.

The regex pattern above says a range of `a-z` followed by `A-Z`.